# Todo list. List all problem

Tags: solidity

I made simple todo list contract.
What i want to achieve is to list all added todos in `function showTodo()`
I know I cant return mapping directly, but im stuck..

So basically each `msg.sender` can add/delete todo, but everyone can list all todos not only `msg.sender` like it is now.

Any ideas ? Every help appreciated. Thanks.

```
contract Todo {

 mapping(address => string[]) todos;


function addTodo(string memory _todo) public{
    todos[msg.sender].push(_todo);
}

function delTodo(uint idx) public{
    require(idx < todos[msg.sender].length);
    delete todos[msg.sender][idx];
    todos[msg.sender][idx] = todos[msg.sender][todos[msg.sender].length - 1];
    todos[msg.sender].pop();

}

function showTodo() public view returns(string[] memory){
    return(todos[msg.sender]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ummm, would you mind rephrasing your problem so that I could try to help you. I can't understand what your issue is.

EDIT :

I got what you meant. The simplest solution would be to add an array of strings that will store every task. Here it is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

contract Todo {

 mapping(address => string[]) todos;
 string[]  public allTodos;


function addTodo(string memory _todo) public{
    todos[msg.sender].push(_todo);
    allTodos.push(_todo);
}

function delTodo(uint idx) public{
    require(idx < todos[msg.sender].length);
    string memory _todo = todos[msg.sender][idx];
    delete todos[msg.sender][idx];
    todos[msg.sender][idx] = todos[msg.sender].[todos[msg.sender].length - 1];
    todos[msg.sender].pop();
    for (uint i; i<allTodos.length; i++) {
        if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_todo))==keccak256(abi.encodePacked(allTodos[i]))) {
         delete allTodos[i];
    }
  }
}





function showTodo() public view returns(string[] memory){
    return(todos[msg.sender]);
}

}
```

You could try this out and now the `delTodo()` function will also delete the string from the `allTodos` array as well.

**Please NOTE**: My proposition for the solution to the problem is not production level. It is generally accepted that loops over arrays should be avoided for smart contract programming, as they are among the most expensive operations.

The `delete` method should also be used with caution because its name is deceiving. It does not delete the designated element of the array, but simply restores it to its default value ( for uint/int its 0, for string its ' '). It DOES NOT change(a.k.a shorten) the length of the array.

I hope I have helped you. Keep hacking! :)

Comment: Hey Peter and thank You for reply. Basically I want to create a function where I can list all tasks added by every msg.sender (every address). For now it is only possible to list tasks added by individual address. 

Example: 1 address .. added a task. 2 address added a task, 3rd and so on, and I want to list all tasks added. 

Thank You in advance

Comment: Ooh, I got you. Edited my answer. It should work as I have tested it.

Comment: Thank You Petar for reply! Ok so my perfect solution will be to return allTodos in function showTodo without msg.sender, but how to make to update it, so when i add to array its adding, but when i delete its unfortunately not deleting .. my problem is that i want to interact it with my dApp and need something like this: `function showTodo() return allTodos`. Thanks!

Comment: For the showTodo function, just try this :
`


function showTodo() public view returns(string[] memory){
    return allTodos;
}
`

Comment: It works, but unfortunately when any msg.sender delete task the function remains the same and lists all the previous tasks added .. do You have any idea ? Btw thank You for your time helping me out :)

Comment: Added some more code to my answer, I hope this time it solves all your problems.

Comment: Petar, first of all thank You for your time spent on my problem. I really appreciate that. Do you think is there actually a way to delete the item instead of restoring it to default value ?

Comment: I think i got it. I have created a struct and event .. along with mapping. Now it finally works as it should.